# Word add-in cannot be installed on Word 2016 (MSO 16.0.4266.1001 64 bits)

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

These days, I have found my add-in cannot be installed on Word 2016 (MSO 16.0.4266.1001 64 bits). No icon showed up in menu. Just open a window like below:

[image: the error]

So I went to [dev.office.com](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets) and found this:

> *Note: The build number for Office 2016 installed via MSI is 16.0.4266.1001. This version only contains the WordApi 1.1 requirement set.

The word **only** crossed my mind, [office-js-helpers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers) was used in my add-in, is this the reason?

Hers is my requirements in manifest.xml:

```
    <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <!--<Set Name="TableBindings" MinVersion="1.1"/>-->
        <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        <!--<Set Name="OOXML" MinVersion="1.1"/>-->
        <!--<Set Name="IdentityAPI" MinVersion="1.1"/>-->
    </Sets>
    </Requirements>
```

I want to know the reason that my add-in is inavailable on Word 2016 (MSO 16.0.4266.1001 64 bits). Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The IdentityAPI requirement set is not supported on Office 2016 MSI.

Comment: Is that `office-js-helpers` depends on `IdentityAPI`? If so, this is the reason. BTY, `IdentityAPI` was commented when I submitted to office store.

Comment: One more thing, is that `IdentityAPI requirement set` not supported on any version of Office 2016 MSI ?

Comment: office-js-helpers does not depend on IdentityAPI. The IdentityAPI is not supported on any version of Office 2016 MSI.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I suppose it's not the reason.